# How to properly handle mixed RF/digital design in HFSS 3Dlayout

Tags: rf, spi, pcb-simulation

I have a big design imported from Altium into HFSS 3DLayout with several RFIC that I want to simulate. RF and Digital (SPI) nets are included in this design.

I'm interested mainly in the RF side of things so when  I cut out of the main design to analyze a specific area the shape of this cut-out is usually driven by the RF nets I want to include in my design. This means that sometimes I can have digital nets floating or partially floating in my sub-design.

I do not want  to remove completely the digital part as I would like to evaluate any possible effect on my RF design, and I'm not sure either that terminating this floating/partially floating nets to ground is the right solution.

How do I handle this situation?